# Hadoop Reducer code parseint command error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am a beginner and still learning hadoop.
I have been trying to solve an assignment for quite some days now but however I am getting error with the reduce job. My code runs fine with Mapper function but not with the reducer one. Any guidance will be appreciated.
Code is simple and about combining values of keys.
Input is:
keys    f1  f2  total
key1    12  1   5
key1    23  1   5
key1    34  1   5
key1    23  1   5
key1    2   1   5
key1    12  1   5
key1    12  1   5
key1    4   1   5
key2    35  2   5
key2    456 2   5
key2    57  2   5
key2    67  2   5
key2    8   2   5
key2    8   2   5
key2    78  2   5
key2    78  2   5
key3    1   3   5
key3    1   3   5
key3    1   3   5
key3    1   3   5

Required output is:
keys    sum(f1) sum(f2) sum(f3) avg(f1)
key1    122 8   40  15.25
key2    787 16  40  98.375
key3    4   12  20  1

I know it is a very simple code but I am stuck somewhere and not been able to solve this problem for a long time now.
My code is:
Mapper:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
//import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
public class AMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
  @Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String a = "";
      String abc="";
        String[] line1 = value.toString().split(",");
        for(int j=1;j<line1.length;j++)
          { if(j==1)
            {
                abc = abc.concat(line1[j]);
            }
          else
          abc = abc.concat("#").concat(line1[j]);           
          }
        a = line1[0];       
        context.write(new Text(a), new Text(abc));
    }
  }
```

Reducer:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class AReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {                 
                  int f[] = new int[3];  
                  f[0]=f[1]=f[2]=0;
      String xyz="";
      for (Text val : values)
      { 
      String[] line1 = val.toString().split("#");
      f[0] = Integer.parseInt(line1[0]) + f[0];
      f[1] = Integer.parseInt(line1[1]) + f[1];
      f[2] = Integer.parseInt(line1[2]) + f[2];
       }     
                xyz= f[0]+"\t"+f[1]+"\t"+f[2];
                context.write(key, new Text(xyz)); 
                f[0]=f[1]=f[2]=0;
    }
```

}

Main:

```
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class Agger {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.out.printf("Usage: Agger <input dir> <output dir>\n");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(Agger.class);
    job.setJobName("Aggregation");

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(AMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(AReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    System.exit(success ? 0 : 1);
  }


}
```

This is the code.
This is the error that i am getting

```
15/03/19 04:53:23 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
15/03/19 04:53:23 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/03/19 04:53:23 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
15/03/19 04:53:23 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
15/03/19 04:53:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201503190444_0003
15/03/19 04:53:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/03/19 04:53:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/03/19 04:53:33 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at AReducer.reduce(AReducer.java:17)
    at AReducer.reduce(AReducer.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_0: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient).
attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_0: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_0: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
15/03/19 04:53:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at AReducer.reduce(AReducer.java:17)
    at AReducer.reduce(AReducer.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_1: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient).
attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_1: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_1: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
15/03/19 04:53:42 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at AReducer.reduce(AReducer.java:17)
    at AReducer.reduce(AReducer.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_2: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient).
attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_2: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
attempt_201503190444_0003_r_000000_2: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201503190444_0003
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 29
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File System Counters
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes read=0
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes written=182376
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of read operations=0
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of large read operations=0
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of write operations=0
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes read=347
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of read operations=2
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of write operations=0
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed reduce tasks=1
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=4
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=1
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=4785
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=19188
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=20
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=20
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=253
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Input split bytes=94
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=20
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=400
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=150429696
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=387174400
15/03/19 04:53:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=160501760
```

I am trying to get the output from mapper as {'key1',1#2#3,2#3#4,3#4#5}.
this output will be fed to the reducer which will split the values and add them up. But somehow the code is not working.
Any kind of help or guidance will be appreciated. Also If anyone can tell me a good site to learn hadoop from will only help me in learning it, so please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no error in your program. You are getting the exception because java is trying to convert null string "" to Integer. Usually this error will come when there is an extra space or extra new line inside your data file (text file).

To avoid these kinds of error enclose the map side and reducer side logic in try catch.

Answer (score 0):

for (Text val : values)
      { 
      String[] line1 = val.toString().split("#");
      f[0] = Integer.parseInt(line1[0]) + f[0];
      f[1] = Integer.parseInt(line1[1]) + f[1];
      f[2] = Integer.parseInt(line1[2]) + f[2];
       }

This is the place where are u getting error , "" cant be parsed into Integer .  Either u handle this in mapper or reducer